# C Linked List - Create Nodes within Memory Block

Tags: c, list, malloc, heap-memory

I am attempting to create a linked list within a pre-allocated block of memory. Put simply,

1. I have an initial memory pool declared like so.

   ```
   void *block = malloc(1000);
   ```
2. I created the head of a linked list from this pool:

   ```
   struct node *root = block;
   ```
3. Let's say the memory address of the initial block is 100000. If I add a single linked list node of size 100, this just starts at 100000 (as it is the first node, sharing the memory address of the first block). If I add a second node of size 200, this should start at 100100 (at the end of the last block). And the next one would start at 100300, and so on.

My method to add nodes to the list can be condensed as follows:

```
void add_node(int size) {
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *current = root;
    while (current != NULL) { //loop to get to the end of the linked list
        ...stuff (irrelevant to this question)...
        current = current->next;
    }
    new_node->value = size;
    current->next = new_node;
}
```

The node definition is pretty generic:

```
struct node {
   int value;
   int free;
   struct node *next;
};
```

The main method is as follows:

```
int main(void) {
    create_block(1000);
    add_node(100);
    add_node(200);
    print_all();
}
```

And print_all simply iterates through and prints out the memory addresses:

```
void print_all() {
    printf("%ld (block start)\n", block);
    struct node* current = root;
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%ld (%d)", current->value);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

However, when adding nodes with values 100 and 200, the memory addresses are as follows:

25770205072 (block start)
25770205072 (location of 100 node - this is ok)
25769968848 (location of 200 node - not ok. This should be 25770205072 + 100)
25770204784 (location of remaining 700 memory node - not ok. This should be 25770205072 + 100 + 200)

Any clues for what I'm doing wrong? I tried a few different approaches without any luck.

Thanks for your time! I appreciate any assistance very much.

Comment: You do not show how you allocate nodes from your pool, while the problem could (should ?) lie there.

Comment: I have edited the post a little. Is this a bit better?

Comment: You are not allocating space for your blocks from your pool, but instead you are allocating new space using malloc. You could keep a counter that starts at root and is incremented by size. Also, please put up your entire code since we don't know what print_all does.

Comment: We would also need to look at the struct definition.

Comment: y go to all this length describing your own memory pool but never use it. I assume 'create_block' sets it up, but you then proceed to malloc your nodes.

Answer (score 0):

*Caveat:* Since you didn't show your pool code, this may not be a complete solution, but `add_node` has some bugs.

You have to set `new_node->next = NULL`

At the end of the loop, `current` could be null unless "stuff irrelevant ..." guarantees non-null. In which case, it's *not* irrelevant.

You need an extra variable (e.g. `prev`)

Also note that because `add_node` is calling `malloc`, it's bypassing your memory pool, so you can't have too many expectations on addresses.

Here's what I think you need [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
void
add_node(int size)
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *current;
    struct node *prev;

    // loop to get to the end of the linked list
    prev = root;
    for (current = root;  current != NULL;  current = current->next) {
        // ... stuff(irrelevant to this question) ...
        prev = current;
    }

    new_node->value = size;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    // NOTE: this assumes root is _always_ non-null
#if 0
    prev->next = new_node;
#else
    if (prev != NULL)
        prev->next = new_node;
    else
        root = new_node;
#endif
}
```

Comment: Oh! This is appreciated. I am most familiar with Java so you can probably tell some of my Java style bled over.

Comment: You're welcome! BTW, your `printf` as written is incorrect (i.e. you're missing the second value). If you compile with `-Wall` [which you should _always_ do], this would be flagged at compile time. Also note that pointers are usually printed using `%p` instead of `%ld`, so I'd do: `printf("%p (%d)\n",current,current->value)`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this was so simple. I literally used what @Ajay Brahmakshatriya mentioned - "You could keep a counter that starts at root and is incremented by size" - and created a new long that starts at the root, and just increment it by size every time. Instead of setting the new node to a new blob of allocated memory, I just set it to the old address + size (and incremented the address appropriately). Works fine now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just try remember about the "linked list" concept...
It different from array which each elemen of array located perfectly next/adjacent from the elemen before, in the memory.

I think each node "dynamically allocated". Program try to find the still free memory and the certain present node can be located far away from previous node. But the size block which node was allocated is depend on how we write malloc code, size to allocate it.

So I think, nothing wrong with your codes..